# Underscore _.each callback when finished?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a callback for when underscore is finished it's `_.each` loop because if I `console log` immediately afterwards obviously the array I am populating with the each loop is not available. This is from a nested `_.each` loop.

```
_.each(data.recipe, function(recipeItem) {
    var recipeMap = that.get('recipeMap');
    recipeMap[recipeItem.id] = { id: recipeItem.id, quantity: recipeItem.quantity };
});
console.log(that.get('recipeMap')); //not ready yet.
```

Comment: `_.each` is synchronous. It does not need a callback. The loop will finish before your `console.log` line is reached. If you're invoking asynchronous functions *inside* the `_.each`, that is as a different problem.

Comment: `_.each` is synchronous, and will only return after the function was executed on all items. If `that.get` is asynchronous, `each` won't help you with that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `each` function in UnderscoreJS is synchronous which wouldn't require a callback when it is finished. One it's done executing the commands immediately following the loop will execute.

If you are performing async operations in your loop, I would recommend using a library that supports async operations within the each function. One possibility is by using [AsyncJS](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

Here is your loop translated to AsyncJS:

```
async.each(data.recipe, function(recipeItem, callback) {
    var recipeMap = that.get('recipeMap');
    recipeMap[recipeItem.id] = { id: recipeItem.id, quantity: recipeItem.quantity };
    callback(); // show that no errors happened
}, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("There was an error" + err);
    } else {
        console.log("Loop is done");
    }
});
```

Comment: however if console something inside of looping, it won't be triggered

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to build your callback function into the each loop on the last execution:

```
_.each(collection, function(model) {
    if(model.collection.indexOf(model) + 1 == collection.length) {
         // Callback goes here
    }
});
```

Edit to add:

I don't know what your input/output data looks like but you might consider using `_.map` instead, if you're just transforming / rearranging the contents