# Do underscore.js functions, such as _.findWhere(), return results synchronously?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I was using `_.findWhere()` in underscore.js to find an object containing a specific property from a collection of such objects. For example:

```
var rules = _.findWhere(rules, {id: ruleId});
if (!rules) {
    // do something 
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Then I started to worry about JavaScript being asynchronous. Do I know that `_.findWhere()` will finish populating the `rules` object by the time the second line is executed? Is this something that I need to consider for every method in underscore.js?

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831655/underscore-each-callback-when-finished) that says `_.each()` is synchronous, but I'm not sure how that was determined, nor am I sure if that answer applies for `_.findWhere()` or other underscore.js functions.

Comment: I'd guess it is synchronous, but I would check the source code. Is it doing anything that is asynchronous?

Comment: Usually, if you don't have callbacks it's synchronous...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe every single function of underscore.js is synchronous, so you don't need to worry about it: every line written after it will be executed after.

Anyway, if it was not synchronous (i.e. asynchronous) it would require a callback, such as

```
// DISCLAIMER: this is a fictionnal code, it is in fact synchronous
_.findWhere(rules, {id: ruleId}, function done() {
    // code to be executed once finished
});
```

If you're still in doubt, you can just test in your browser's console `_.findWhere([{a:true},{a:false}], {a:true})`: if you see a result in the console then it was synchronous (note that I'm not familiar with underscore so not sure about my test-example)

Comment: A couple of the functions are async/wrappers, such as `_.throttle`, `_.debounce`, `_.defer`, etc. But for the most part they are sync

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I guess it is still safe to consider everything to be synchronous as when someone uses defer amd the like he likely knows why.

Answer (score 2):

They are synchronous.

See for yourself: [_.findWhere](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L320), [_.matches](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1307), [_.find](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L232), [_.findIndex](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L232), [createIndexFinder](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L676). There is no instance of `setTimeout` in those functions.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of JavaScript is synchronous unless stated otherwise.

Asynchronous functions will have callbacks or return promises. But again the majority of functions / methods in various libraries that have callbacks are not asynchronous.