# Nodejs variable prints on console but not on the view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

the code is this

```
module.exports = {
index: function (req, res, next) {
    //get an array of all users in user collection
    Notification.find(function foundNotification(err, notifications) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        var elusuario=[];
        User.findOne(2, function foundUser (err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) return next();
            console.log(user);
            console.log("----------------------------");
            elusuario = user;
            console.log(elusuario);
        });
        res.view({
            notifications: notifications,
            elusuario: elusuario
        });
    })

}
```

};

That is the controller and in the console prints elusuario good but in the view the user hasn't values. why?
i think is something is something related to the globals variables. but i dont know
thanks

EDIT

all right so the method is async. what im trying to do is find the notifications and the user by her user.id and get the user.name so what if i do this

```
module.exports = {
index: function (req, res, next) {

    //get an array of all users in user collection
    Notification.find(function foundNotification(err, notifications) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        User.find(function foundUser (err, users) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            var usuarios_locotes = [];
            _.each(notifications, function (notification) {

                _.each(users, function (user) {
                    if(notification.token_user==user.token){
                        console.log(user.token);
                        usuarios_locotes.push(user);
                        console.log(usuarios_locotes);
                    };
                });
            });

            res.view({
                notifications: notifications,
                users: usuarios_locotes
            });
        });

    })
}
```

};

it still not working? the __.each is an async funtion to?

sorry for all this maybe stupid questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `findOne` of `User` object runs asynchronously. Because of this, you are rendering the view before the `findOne` returns the user object.

If you put a `console.log` before the `render.view`, it'll print the output before the `console.log` inner `findOne` method.

Comment: sorry, I've just edit the question, have u any idea why this not work:/

Comment: About the `_.each`, I found another answer that will help you better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831655/underscore-each-callback-when-finished#answer-18833980

Answer (score 1):

When the code is running, the function `foundNotification` is not executed before you call the `res.view`. My advice for you is read about Promises.

You can change your code as below to work:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    //get an array of all users in user collection
    Notification.find(function foundNotification(err, notifications) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        var elusuario=[];
        User.findOne(2, function foundUser (err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) return next();
            console.log(user);
            console.log("----------------------------");
            elusuario = user;
            console.log(elusuario);
            res.view({
                notifications: notifications,
                elusuario: elusuario
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the **findOne** Method is an asynchrone method,so it's executed without provinding the **res.view** with the appropriate data
try to wrap the whole logic in the same function, it may look ugly but it ll do the thing for now

Answer (score 0):

All right so.. first really thanks to everybody. I solve this shit.

I know this is not the right way to do this but it works, so for my proposes it's fine.

the problem after the EDIT was that in the view I'm trying to write an object with parameters but what I've was sending was vector of vector so changing this line:

```
usuarios_locotes.push(new Object(users[h]));
```

I can send a vector of objects.

So.. anyway thanks cause later i will change my code to do it better and efficient

This was my first post so sorry for not read the first steps of how to use this haha cause i think i have been make a lot of mistakes.

And sorry for my English :C