# NodeJS wait before callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a script that requests an inventory with items inside from a 3rd party service and then it has to filter them based on certain criteria. Although the `Filter` module send back the correct response the method that calls the Filter fails to add the items that have passed the test in to an array.

More specifically `Inventory.loadClean()` fetches the data from the 3rd party api and then it calls `Inventory.filter` which is responsible for looping through the items and checking if they pass the criteria. If the items does then it adds it in to an array.

**Method call**

```
// This is how Intentory.filter is called. All the parameters are correct.
Inventory.filter(inv, rules, function(filtered) {
    console.log(filtered);
    next(filtered);
 });
```

**Inventory.filter**

```
filter: function (inv, rules, cb) {
    var filtered_items = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {
        Filter.itemPasses(inv[i], rules, function(passes, stage) {
            //console.log(passes, stage);
            if(passes) {
                filtered_items.push(inv[i]);
            }
            if(i + 1 == inv.length) {
                console.log("i+1:", i+1, "inv:", inv.length);
                cb(filtered_items);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's fairly straight forward. `Filter.itemPasses` evaluates the item and in the callback the value `passes` is either true or false based on whether the item passes the checks or not.

The if statement that evaluates the expression `i + 1 == inv.length` was found here: [Underscore _.each callback when finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831655/underscore-each-callback-when-finished)

and the idea is that you call the callback when the last element is processed. Although it seems very logical for it to work, it doesn't. Im still getting an empty array.

Please note that i have check ALL the methods inside my `Filter` and they are evaluating correctly. Just in case you wanna see the `filter.js` here is a link: https://gist.github.com/meletisf/d32a241ba2cbb168527f4342eabdf2a6

I'm pretty sure that it has to be an issue with the async but im not sure it is caused.

Comment: `Filter.meetsPriceLimits` has a call to `Cache.get()`. Could it be that this function answers asynchronuously? A callback with a `resp` parameter could raise that suspicion.

Comment: Yes. `Cache.get()` i an async wrapper for Redis. I knew that this was causing issues but i though that by using multiple callbacks the script would work as itented. Anyways, check my answer below on how i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats maybe a race problem. This might be a better condition for the callback, and also closure i:

```
filter: function (inv, rules, cb) {
 var filtered_items = [];
 var count=0;
 for(let i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {//the let is important
    Filter.itemPasses(inv[i], rules, function(passes, stage) {
        //console.log(passes, stage);
        if(passes) {
            filtered_items.push(inv[i]);
        }
        count++;
        if(count == inv.length) {//the improved condition
            console.log("i+1:", i+1, "inv:", inv.length);
            cb(filtered_items);
        }
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Now it returns an array of 18 undefined elements. 18 is the number of items that passes the test.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to inspect how each variable was behaving i stumbled upon the following conclusion.

The variable `i` from the `for` loop was behaving strange inside the the `Inventory.filter` method. More specifically it was always 31. Not sure why this was happening but it was clear to me that i should get the current item from `inv[i]`. Instead i change the `Filter.itemPasses` to return the item object if it passes all the criteria. I also added the code that Jonas suggested. I dont know why it works but it works. Without it the array is always empty.

Unfortunately i dont know the exact answer on why the code was so messed up but by implementing the fix i mentioned below i got it to work.

Comment: You are defining `var i` in the function scope outside the loop. Since the callback is called asynchronuously, at the time it is called, the loop already has finished, and `i` has reached its final value.

Comment: have a look at *closures inside for loops - simple practical examples* here on SO